# How to loop through XML with same elements which are not enclosed by a parent element in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have this:

```
DECLARE @accountIds XML = '<AccountId>1</AccountId><AccountId>2</AccountId>'
    SELECT [aid].[Col].value('/AccountId', 'BIGINT')
    FROM @accountIds.nodes('/') as [aid]([Col])
```

The problem is that I dont know what to put in the first select item to get all the text enclosed by AccountId tags. I only know how to get 1 text

```
DECLARE @accountIds XML = '<AccountId>1</AccountId><AccountId>2</AccountId>'
    SELECT [aid].[Col].value('/AccountId[1]', 'BIGINT')
    FROM @accountIds.nodes('/') as [aid]([Col])
```

or

```
DECLARE @accountIds XML = '<AccountId>1</AccountId><AccountId>2</AccountId>'
    SELECT [aid].[Col].value('/AccountId[2]', 'BIGINT')
    FROM @accountIds.nodes('/') as [aid]([Col])
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for. If at all you want to list the values then here is the query DECLARE @accountIds XML = '<AccountId>1</AccountId><AccountId>2</AccountId>'
    SELECT [aid].[Col].value('(.)[1]', 'BIGINT')
    FROM @accountIds.nodes('/AccountId') as [aid]([Col])

Comment: Yep bro.  This is what I wanted. tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go..

```
    DECLARE @accountIds XML = '<AccountId>1</AccountId><AccountId>2</AccountId>' 
SELECT [aid].[Col].value('(.)[1]', 'BIGINT') FROM @accountIds.nodes('/AccountId') as [aid]([Col])
```